# Joint continuity implies separate continuity in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

I need to prove that for a function $f: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ joint continuity at $(x_0, y_0)$ implies separate continuity. I went for an epsilon-delta style proof but have not got anywhere. Am I in the right track? I have seen posts alrerady commenting on this but Iam looking for a simpler proof or explanation.

[This is what I got for the moment:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7n2BT.jpg)

Thank you, any help is welcome.

Comment: Can you write your proposed $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof? Should really just be a trivial unwinding of definitions.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I edited it with what I got

Comment: Ok you really should type that up. Now, it's good that you wrote out what you know and what you're trying to show, because it lets us know your error. In your case, the "we want to show" stuff isn't really right. It should be "for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|y-y_0|<\delta\implies |f(x_0,y)-f(x_0,y_0)|<\epsilon$". Remember, $f(x_0,\cdot)$ is a function of one-variable $y\mapsto f(x_0,\cdot)$, and you're trying to show continuity at $y_0$. Having said this, you're really almost done; there's no need to mess around with triangle inequalities.

Comment: We have $|y-y_0|=\|(x_0,y)-(x_0,y_0)\|$ (using say the Euclidean norm), so if $|y-y_0|<\delta$, then $\|(x_0,y)-(x_0,y_0)\|<\delta$ clearly. And therefore by the stuff you already know...

Comment: Thanks a lot @peek-a-boo